# Linked List pointers prob

Tags: c

I do not know why this is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// struct of list
typedef struct noeud
{
    int adresse, taille, temp;
    struct noeud* suivant;

} * liste;

int random(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + (rand() % ((b + 1) + a)));
}

void initialisation(liste* LBO)
{
    *LBO = NULL;
}
```

I think it's here the problem when I create `q` (`q` is created to point to the previous node).

```
void creation(liste* LBO)
{
    liste q, prec = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (i < 3)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
        q = malloc(sizeof(liste));

        if (*LBO == NULL)
        {
            q->adresse = 0;
            q->taille = random(5, 45);
            q->temp = random(5, 15);
            q->suivant = *LBO;
            *LBO = q;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            prec = *LBO;
            q->taille = random(5, 45);
            q->temp = random(5, 15);
            q->adresse = prec->adresse + prec->taille;
            q->suivant = *LBO;
            *LBO = q;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void affichage(liste LBO)
{
    printf("\nvoici ta liste \n ");
    while (LBO != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-->", LBO->taille);
        LBO = LBO->suivant;
    }
    if (LBO == NULL)
        printf("NULL");
}

int main()
{
    // or here
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    liste LBO;
    initialisation(&LBO);

    creation(&LBO);

    affichage(LBO);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This needs some serious editing. I tried, but gave up.

Comment: try using debugger to find what's causing the problem. To solve the problem, you first need to know what it is

Comment: Indent (format) your code, just like the samples in your C textbook.

Comment: ... and what is your program supposed to do ?

Comment: @unwind Done, http://format.krzaq.cc/, file style :p.

Comment: This is the problem with using non-English identifiers in your code. It now substantially reduces the amount of people that can read and understand it at a glance. Oh, and don't hide pointers behind a typedef, that's a source of endless confusion.

Comment: You are confusing pointers with pointers-to-pointers.  Look at your compiler errors.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

Instead of calling

```
 initialisation(&LBO);
```

which is not really wrong, just write:

```
LBO = NULL;
```

Then don't hide pointers with `typedef`s, it only adds confusion.

Instead of:

```
typedef struct noeud
{
  int adresse, taille, temp;
  struct noeud* suivant;

} *liste;
```

Write:

```
struct noeud
{
  int adresse, taille, temp;
  struct noeud* suivant;    
};
```

and use `struct noeud*` instead of `liste`.

**Now the real problem:**

This is wrong. Here you allocate the size for a pointer, but you need to allocate the size for the whole structure:

```
q = malloc(sizeof(liste));
```

which is actually the same as:

```
q = malloc(sizeof(struct noeud*))
```

but you need:

```
q = malloc(sizeof(struct noeud))
```

You see now why hiding pointers with typedefs is a bad idea.

So here is the corrected version of your program (`#include`s ommitted for brevity):

```
struct noeud
{
  int adresse, taille, temp;
  struct noeud* suivant;
};

int random(int a, int b)
{
  return (a + (rand() % ((b + 1) + a)));
}

void creation(struct noeud** LBO)
{
  struct noeud* q, *prec = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  // srand(time(NULL));  <<<<< don't call srand here, call it once at the 
                            // beginning of the program
  while (i < 3)
  {
    printf("%d", i);
    q = malloc(sizeof(struct noeud));

    if (*LBO == NULL)
    {
      q->adresse = 0;
      q->taille = random(5, 45);
      q->temp = random(5, 15);
      q->suivant = *LBO;
      *LBO = q;
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      prec = *LBO;
      q->taille = random(5, 45);
      q->temp = random(5, 15);
      q->adresse = prec->adresse + prec->taille;
      q->suivant = *LBO;
      *LBO = q;
      i++;
    }
  }
}

void affichage(struct noeud* LBO)
{
  printf("\nvoici ta struct noeud* \n ");
  while (LBO != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d-->", LBO->taille);
    LBO = LBO->suivant;
  }
  // if (LBO == NULL)  <<<<<<<<<<< drop this, LBO is always NULL here
                                // but it doesn't hurt, it's just useless
    printf("NULL");
}

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));   // <<<<<<<<<<<<< call srand here
  struct noeud* LBO;
  LBO = NULL;

  creation(&LBO);

  affichage(LBO);
  return 0;
}
```

There is still room for improvement, especially the `creation` function is somewhat awkward.

Also look at the comments with `<<<<<<<<<<<`, there are minor corrections